# Optimal join in two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, join, query-performance

I have a table (T1) with ca. 500000 non duplicate records:

```
ID1    Relation  ID2
4      Rel4      13
5      Rel5       4
13     Rel13     16
16     Rel16     5
```

I have the properties table T1_Prop:

```
ID    Entity    
4     Ent4     
5     Ent5
13    Ent13   
16    Ent16
```

I want to join these two tables (based on id : 4) in an efficient way as follows:

```
 Entity   Relation   Entity
 Ent4      Rel4      Ent13  
 Ent5      Rel5      EntEnt4
```

I designed this select statement including JOIN which works fine. However, I am not sure if this the best way to do:

```
select 
  a.entity, 
  r.relation, 
  b.entity 
from T1 as r 
INNER JOIN T1_Prop as a ON a.ID=r.ID1 AND (r.ID1=4 OR r.ID2=4) 
INNER JOIN T1_Prop as b ON b.ID=r.ID2;
```

Comment: Optimizing questions belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Best in terms of what?

Comment: In term of efficiency. I just want to use MySQL as its and I am not trying to improve it with some exernal libraries or so

Comment: Plese provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can see if it came out efficiently.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the engine, indexes, datatypes, etc.

Comment: Do the `EXPLAIN` for the suggested answers, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fine use of SQL. It's built for this kind of query.

You'll need two covering indexes to speed this up, on `T1`.  They are:

```
(ID1, ID2, relation)
```

and

```
(ID2, ID1, relation)
```

The two indexes are for handling the `OR` clause. It is the only potential performance issue I see, and that's just because `OR` operations sometimes trick the query planner into doing too much table scanning.

Try refactoring your query to this to make your selection of ID values more visible.

```
select   a.entity, r.relation, b.entity 
  from T1 as r 
 INNER JOIN T1_Prop as a ON a.ID=r.ID1  
 INNER JOIN T1_Prop as b ON b.ID=r.ID2
 WHERE (r.ID1=4 OR r.ID2=4)
```

Then, if you have trouble with performance, after you create the covering indexes, refactor it again to

```
select   a.entity, r.relation, b.entity 
  from T1 as r 
 INNER JOIN T1_Prop as a ON a.ID=r.ID1  
 INNER JOIN T1_Prop as b ON b.ID=r.ID2
 WHERE r.ID1=4 
UNION
select   a.entity, r.relation, b.entity 
  from T1 as r 
 INNER JOIN T1_Prop as a ON a.ID=r.ID1  
 INNER JOIN T1_Prop as b ON b.ID=r.ID2
 WHERE r.ID2=4
```

Comment: Make that `UNION ALL`, which will be more efficient than the unnecessary de-dupping of the default.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine except for the first `ON` clause. The condition `(r.ID1=4 OR r.ID2=4)` is not a rule for which record from `T1_Prop` to join to the `T1` record. It is rather a condition, which `T1` records to consider and belongs hence in the `WHERE` clause.

```
select 
  a.entity AS entity1, 
  r.relation, 
  b.entity AS entity2
FROM t1 AS r 
INNER JOIN t1_prop AS a ON a.id = r.id1
INNER JOIN t1_prop AS b ON b.id = r.id2
WHERE r.id1 = 4 OR r.id2 = 4;
```

This won't change the execution plan; the DBMS will execute this just the same. But it's more readable as it shows the actual intention: get relations where one of the IDs is 4 and join the entities to those relations.

Another option to show this intention is:

```
select 
  a.entity AS entity1, 
  r.relation, 
  b.entity AS entity2
FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE r.id1 = 4 OR r.id2 = 4) AS r 
INNER JOIN t1_prop AS a ON a.id = r.id1
INNER JOIN t1_prop AS b ON b.id = r.id2;
```

Some consider subqueries in FROM less readable, but, well, others don't. And when queries get more complex and say you even deal with aggregates from different tables, this is often the way to go and build a clean query.

Neither of above queries is actually better or worse than the other.

Comment: The subquery takes extra, unnecessary effort.

Comment: @Rick James: Which? The DBMS should come to the same execution plan for the two queries, provided its optimizer works well. If MySQL doesn't yet, then it all depends on its current implementation which could support the first or the second query better. Maybe MySQL does have problems with derived tables in its current version; I don't know. But even if that is the case, it may already be different in the next version :-)

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the two should say whether the Optimizer has gotten smarter.  This _might_ be something that improved in about 5.7.